# Text gets cut off when publishing Excel Range to HTML

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

to automatise some business process I am copying a Excel cell range into a outlook mail. I use the HTML method to insert the range into the mail body. However, the top of the range is a "normal" table with clear bounderies. Below the table there is some freetext (written into 1 cells at the beginning).

If the freetext is longer than the range of the table, then the text is cutted and not displayed.

Is there a workaround?

Find attached the section of the code where the HTML file is generated (and the text is cut). As well as a screenshot for illustration.

```
rng.copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


'Publish the sheet to a htm file
'Until here Text is displayed correctly. 
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

[image: Screenshot]

The very last two words of the textfile should display:

- **football** instead of footba
- **treehouse** instead of treeho

As you can see this is due to the fact that the text would go beyond the boundary of the table range.

Thanks for your help. Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the text does not go outside or hidden within the html table data/cell, you can use **.AutoFit** to make the column widths match the text length in the cells, before saving as an html file.

This will ensure that the width of the html table accommodates all of the text.

Just add the following line: **.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit**

Here is the updated section of code:

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
.Cells(1).Select
.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' Added line of code to make column widths match the text length
Application.CutCopyMode = False
On Error Resume Next
.DrawingObjects.Visible = True
.DrawingObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Your solution fits the very first column to the text (which definitely solves the problem but at cost of "design") But I used your approach to determine the pixel length of the "longest" text and converted it to the normal width unit used by excel to distribute the t width among the used columns to fit the text. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Maeaex1 Good to see it work for you and that you could adapt it to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will trim a line of text to fit within a specified width:

```
Function TrimTextToWidth(Text As String, Width As Double) As String
    'We need to put the Text into a Shape to measure the width
    'You may need to change the Font Formatting of the Shape to match your cell
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 10 * (Len(Text) + 1), (30 * (1 + Len(Text) - Len(Replace(Text, vbLf, "")))))
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Text
        'Trim the text until it fits within the width
        While (.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.BoundWidth > Width) And Len(.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text) > 0
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Left(.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, Len(.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text) - 1)
        Wend
        TrimTextToWidth = .TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
        'Remove the shape when we have finished with it
        .Delete
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Quick question regarding the function. I did a test creating a string based on two cells e.g. teststr = Range(A1:A2).Text for the Function. But the function stops with error code "Object required" in the "With" line.
Moreover, I am not sure how to get the trimmed text together with the inital "rng" range for the HTML publishing. 

Outlook requires as far as I know a consequent TextBody (in this case "rng") to be displayed in the mail

Comment: @Maeaex1 You would probably need to duplicate the Sheet or Range, and then replace the text/Value in `rng` with the trimmed version.  If you are getting an error on the `With` line, check if the ActiveSheet is locked (which would prevent you from creating the Shape)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your quick response!